# User defined method doesn't exist laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

I have defined a custom class (in model without a reference table), it's properties and methods. I am trying to return a response from a controller using the methods of my model. I created a new instance of that class and set the properties. var_dump() works just fine, but i am unable to call the method of that class. How do i do it ??

My model is something like this:

```
<?php
class Response extends Eloquent{
public $property1;
public function return_property(){
return $this->property1;
}
```

My code to get that value is something like this:

```
$response = new Response;
$response->property1 = $somevalue;
$response->return_property();
```

I am unable to call that method after my comupation. Please help

Comment: You're trying to change the value of property1, but where will you be getting this from?

Comment: I'm sorry... didn't read the 2nd part of your code. Ignore the above statement. Have you tried doing a `$response->save();` first?

Comment: yes..$response->save() also didn't get me the result.

Comment: Wh t do you mean by "I am unable to call that method"? Do you get any errors or is the method called, but does not do/return what you expecT?

Comment: Are you sure you are calling the right `Response` class?

Comment: the error i get is.. BadMethodCallException and Method return_property doesnot exists.